# Plotting surface with gnuplot, but I only have a Z-data datafile

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file containing z values (m x n = 2068 x 100), but I fail to find a way to make a surface plot in `gnuplot` out of that.
In MATLAB the command is straight forward: just `surf(M)`.

The values correspond to readouts over time from a spectrometer, i.e.

```
wavelength scan1   scan2     scan3     scan4
772.7    3.9609    3.9623    3.9593    3.9643
772.8    2.4688    2.4749    2.4669    2.4689
772.9    2.7233    2.7250    2.7240    2.7270
```

I understand that `gnuplot` expects the data to be presented in x,y,z fashion, but my data does not provide that.  I'm sorry that I can find no other way to describe what I'm after...
Essentially: the x values are in the first row, but the y values should be the index of the *column* if that makes sense.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `help image` and `help matrix`... maybe something like `plot "filename" matrix columnheaders rowheaders with image` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data format is halfway between the two formats gnuplot knows about. `splot $DATA matrix` treats all values as z values (no x or y specified). `splot $DATA matrix nonuniform` expects the first column to contain y values and the first row to contain x values. You have one column of coordinate data but not one row of coordinate data.

It looks like your x values are evenly spaced, so it would produce a valid surface to ignore them:

```
splot 'matrix.dat' matrix skip 1 every 1::1
```

- `matrix` tells gnuplot it is an array of z values
- `skip 1` tells it to skip the first row, which contains labels rather than z
- `every 1::1` tells it to read every column starting with column 1 (i.e. skip column 0)

[image]

However a much better approach is to draw a separate line for each scan rather than trying to treat it as a surface:

```
set ylabel "Scan" offset 5
set xlabel "Wavelength" offset 0,-2
set xtics .1 offset 0,-1
unset ytics
unset ztics
splot for [col=2:*] 'matrix.dat' using 1:(col):col title columnhead
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much; indeed, I was very close to your 2nd solution but did not realize that I would have to put `(col)` in there to iterate over all the columns.
Also, I did not know about the `matrix` plotting feature, which - to me at least - was rather obscure to find, as it is not mentioned in the documentation for gnuplot in the chapter on 3D plots? Or maybe I have just missed it. Thanks again.